# Auto share web content on my facebook wall

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I have a classified website for user to post anything to sell. When user confirm posting on my website. i would like to post his/her selling item in my fb wall as well to get more audiences. Does anyone know what to look for? In trying to research but share and like button are not my solution. Many thanks

Comment: whenever someone tries to autopost, a fairy dies...what you are trying to do is most likely not allowed. each and every single post must be approved by the user and the message parameter must be unique and 100% user generated.

Comment: that being said, your question is way too broad for stackoverflow. you need to start reading the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to take a look at the Facebook PHP SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

You will need to sign is as a developer with Facebook and create an app for your website. You'll find examples on the developer website that will help you.